# Update Query with Correlated Subquery

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql

I'm trying to convert a Foxpro application into .NET.  As part of that conversion I'm converting the data from DBF tables to Sql server.

I need to come up with a couple new fields in the Customer table based on the Orders table, FirstOrder and LastOrder.

I just can't seem to muddle through how to do this in TSql.  I know how I'd do it in Foxpro, and I could actually still do it there if I had to, but I know I need to learn how to do this in Sql.

Here is the basic structure.
Customer Table has an Id, then the FirstOrder and LastOrder fields I need updated.
Order Table has OrderDate, but here is the real curve.  The Customer Id can exist in 5 different fields inside the Order: ShipperId, PickupId, ConsigneeId, DeliveryId, or BillingId.

So something like:

```
UPDATE customers
SET FirstOrderDate = 
(Select MIN(OrderDate)
FROM Orders o
WHERE o.ShipperId = Customers.Id or
o.PickupId = Customers.Id or
o.ConsigneeId = Customers.Id or
o.DeliveryId = Customers.Id or
o.BillingId = Customers.Id)
```

Just can't seem to find out how to tie the subquery with the main update query.

Thanks,
-Sid

---

EDIT:
Here's the SELECT that's working based on MarkD's suggestion:

```
Select C.Id,Min(o.OrderDate) as firstorder, MAX(o.OrderDate) as lastorder
from Customers C
JOIN Orders o
on o.ShipperId = C.Id or
        o.PickupId = C.Id or
        o.ConsigneeId = C.Id or
        o.DeliveryId = C.Id or
        o.BillingId = C.Id 
GROUP BY C.Id
```

So now do I use this as a subquery or cursor to post back to the Customers table?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although I think the `JOIN` criteria is highly unlikely, it looks like you're trying to do this?

EDIT: I've modified the `JOIN` criteria but this is what you're after.
`Grouping By` columns that are `OR`'d is odd.

```
;WITH MinOrderDates AS
(
    SELECT   CustID 
            ,OrderDate  = MIN(OrderDate)
    FROM Orders
    GROUP BY CustID
)

UPDATE C
SET FirstOrderDate = MIN(O.OrderDate)
FROM Customers      C
JOIN MinOrderDates  O   ON C.Id = O.CustID
```

This is what your query would look like with the `OR`s

```
;WITH MinOrderDates AS
(
    SELECT   ShipperId
            ,PickupId
            ,ConsigneeId
            ,DeliveryId
            .BillingId
            ,OrderDate  = MIN(OrderDate)
    FROM Orders
    GROUP BY ShipperId
            ,PickupId
            ,ConsigneeId
            ,DeliveryId
            .BillingId
)

UPDATE C
SET FirstOrderDate = MIN(O.OrderDate)
FROM Customers      C
JOIN MinOrderDates  O   ON o.ShipperId     = C.Id or
                           o.PickupId      = C.Id or
                           o.ConsigneeId   = C.Id or
                           o.DeliveryId    = C.Id or
                           o.BillingId     = C.Id
```

EDIT: Though I am having a hard time finding fault with your posted syntax.

Comment: Sql server doesn't like the aggregate function in the set command.  It does work as a SELECT and I can get the data I'm looking for so should I use that answer and try and use it as a subquery or cursor and then run the update into Customers?

Comment: Mark - Thanks for the suggestions.  The min or max date I'm looking for out of the orders is based on the Customer.Id.  This Id can exist in any of the 5 Order Id fields.  Your Group By is based on all of the Id's so the MinOrderDate returns a min OrderDate for the combination of all 5 Id's. The scenario is Customer 123 can be a shipper, or can be a pickup, or can be a Consignee, or a Delivery, or a Billing customer.  I don't care which one, I just want the first order where Customer 123 was involved.

Comment: Mark, you were right.  My post did have the right syntax!  For some reason when I was trying to run it in the query window I must have had a typo.  That's the problem when you're not confident in your grasp of the syntax!!!!  Well, I must be learning something.  Now the only issue is that it takes over a minute to run, where the select statement returns in a few seconds.  Seems like trying to incorporate the select and then an update might be faster.  Thanks again for the assistance!

Comment: Very strange query :) Sorry I couldn't have been more helpful. Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
UPDATE customers
SET FirstOrderDate = 
(Select MIN(OrderDate)
FROM Orders
WHERE ShipperId = Customers.Id or
PickupId = Customers.Id or
ConsigneeId = Customers.Id or
DeliveryId = Customers.Id or
BillingId = Customers.Id)
```