# sql update with group by clause

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am trying to update all instances of [xEndAtach] in tblDoc with [EndDoc] from tbldoc, i am pivoting on tbldoc.[begdoc#] = tblWR001.[begdoc#] and grouping by tbldoc.[xBegAttach]

```
update tbldoc set td.xEndAttach = max(td.[EndDoc#])
from tblWR001 tR join tbldoc tD on td.[begdoc#] = tr.[begDoc#]
group by td.[xBegAttach]
```

I am getting an error trying to use the [group by] clause... not sure how to work arround that.

thanks for your help in advance guys/gals!

Comment: Similar question asked http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14295152/update-query-with-correlated-subquery uses min but is also doing an update on a join with a group by and uses a CTE to do it.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this...  it has to first select the max for the correlated table being updated then it can assign the value.

```
update tbldoc set td.xEndAttach = (SELECT max(td.[EndDoc#])
from tblWR001 tR join tbldoc tD on td.[begdoc#] = tr.[begDoc#]
group by td.[xBegAttach])
```

Comment: this works, but for some reason it is not updating the very last record of each group

Comment: i will troubleshoot and try to figure it out.

Comment: The only way I can see that happening is if the tr.[begDoc#] doesn't match the td.[begdoc#] for the same group.

Comment: i forgot to mention that i have multiple groups, i am now getting an error msg that reads this: Msg 512, Level 16, State 1, Line 5
Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.
The statement has been terminated.

Comment: include on the join within the select the groups provided they are defined in both TR and TD.  if not i'd have to think about this some more.  This also assumes that the two values joined with the addition of group are unique, if not you'll get the same error.

Comment: this is the code i am trying now:
update tbldoc set tbldoc.xEndAttach = (SELECT max(td.[EndDoc#])
from WR001_DAT tR join tbldoc tD on td.[begdoc#] = tr.[BegBates]
group by td.[xOrgEndAttch])
where tbldoc.[xVolume] = 'WR_001'

Comment: what was added was:  where tbldoc.[xVolume] = 'WR_001'

Comment: Did this get you to the desired results?

Comment: nope, using the: " where tbldoc.[xVolume] = 'WR_001'" or not, makes no difference... my problem is that there are multiple groups in this subquery, but i need to update multiple groups.

Comment: I would recommend creating a [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com) with some sample data we can troubleshoot from there easier.

Comment: Basically it allows you to create the tables, populate some sample data that show the problem you're having, and allows us to troubleshoot.  By going through these motions not only do you learn more about SQL, but you may solve your own problem; or enable others to better assist.  I would also look at the comment on teh original post; it may solve the problem as well.

Comment: yah, i tried using the same syntax i use in SQL to create tables and it is giving me errors... do you think we can go to chat? i can explain it easier there, but i do not have enough points to initiate a chat(4 points short)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/54675/discussion-between-lyosha-and-xqbert).

Comment: Sadly I can't from my current location.

Comment: ok, i made a quick image to kind of explain what is going on, all of those fields are now in 1 table [link](http://i.imgur.com/AwdTBcm.jpg)

Comment: i am grouping by [xOrgEndAttach] btw.