# Instead of using nested cursor, Is there another way of comparing rows in 2 different tables and updateding 1 table if the condition is true?

Tags: t-sql

I am using a nested cursor to compare rows from 2 tables.

If the IF statement is true, then I'm updating one column in tbl_1

The problem is that I have 100,000 rows in each tbl_1 and tbl_2 and the performance is terrible.

Is there any other way I can accomplish this without using cursors?

I am using a nested cursor to compare rows from 2 tables. My query gives me the correct information when I test a small date set from the tables but when I test the full data set the query funs for 3 hrs.

```
create table tbl_1 (
 start_date         varchar(8),
 begintime          varchar(4), 
 endtime            varchar(4), 
 duration           varchar(4), 
 interval           varchar(4), 
 color          varchar(10),    
 description        varchar(75),
 )


insert into tbl_1 values('20190102',    '0830', '1200', '210',  '15',   'green',    'Dorothy')
insert into tbl_1 values('20190102',    '1300', '1730', '270',  '15',   'green',    'Dorothy')
insert into tbl_1 values('20190103',    '0830', '1200', '210',  '15',   'green',    'Dorothy')
insert into tbl_1 values('20190103',    '1300', '1730', '270',  '15',   'green',    'Dorothy')
insert into tbl_1 values('20190104',    '0830', '1200', '210',  '15',   'green',    'Dorothy')
insert into tbl_1 values('20190104',    '1300', '1730', '270',  '15',   'green',    'Dorothy')



 create table tbl_2 (
 appt_date          varchar(8),
 begintime          varchar(4), 
 endtime            varchar(4), 
 duration           varchar(4), 
 description            varchar(75),
 )

insert into tbl_2 values('20190102',    '0830', '0900', '30',   'Dorothy')
insert into tbl_2 values('20190102',    '0930', '0945', '15',   'Dorothy')
insert into tbl_2 values('20190102',    '0945', '1000', '15',   'Dorothy')
insert into tbl_2 values('20190102',    '1300', '1315', '15',   'Dorothy')
insert into tbl_2 values('20190102',    '1300', '1330', '30',   'Dorothy')
insert into tbl_2 values('20190107',    '1300', '1330', '30',   'Dorothy')


DECLARE @appt_date          VARCHAR(8)
DECLARE @begintime          VARCHAR(4)
DECLARE @endtime            VARCHAR(4)
DECLARE @duration           int
DECLARE @description        VARCHAR(75)

DECLARE @start_date2            VARCHAR(8)
DECLARE @begintime2             VARCHAR(4)
DECLARE @endtime2               VARCHAR(4)
DECLARE @duration2              int
DECLARE @interval2              int 
DECLARE @color2                 VARCHAR(10)
DECLARE @description2           VARCHAR(75)

DECLARE appt_cursor CURSOR FOR

    select 
    appt_date, begintime, endtime, duration, description
    from tbl_2
    order by appt_date, begintime 

OPEN appt_cursor;
 FETCH NEXT FROM appt_cursor INTO @appt_date, @begintime, @endtime, @duration, @description

 WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
 BEGIN
 DECLARE slot_cursor CURSOR FOR

select  start_date,begintime, endtime, duration, interval, color, description
from tbl_1
order by description, start_date, begintime

 OPEN slot_cursor;
 FETCH NEXT FROM slot_cursor INTO @start_date2, @begintime2, @endtime2, @duration2, @interval2, @color2, @description2;

 WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
 BEGIN


IF @appt_date = @start_date2 and @begintime >= @begintime2 and @begintime <= @endtime2 and @endtime >= @begintime and @endtime <= @endtime2 and @description = @description2

    update tbl_1
    set duration = duration-@duration
    where @appt_date = start_date and @begintime >= begintime and @begintime <= endtime and @endtime >= begintime and @endtime <= endtime and @description = description

  FETCH NEXT FROM slot_cursor INTO @start_date2, @begintime2, @endtime2, @duration2, @interval2, @color2, @description2;
 END;
 CLOSE slot_cursor;
 DEALLOCATE slot_cursor;


 FETCH NEXT FROM appt_cursor INTO @appt_date, @begintime, @endtime, @duration, @description;
END
CLOSE appt_cursor;
DEALLOCATE appt_cursor;
```

I'm getting the desired output.

I'm looking to have the duration column in tbl_1 updated each time the If condition is true.

My results should look like this: The duration column in row 1 and row 2 has been updated.

```
start_date  begintime   endtime duration    interval    color   description
 20190102   0830        1200    150         15          green   Dorothy
 20190102   1300        1730    225         15          green   Dorothy
 20190103   0830        1200    210         15          green   Dorothy
 20190103   1300        1730    270         15          green   Dorothy
 20190104   0830        1200    210         15          green   Dorothy
 20190104   1300        1730    270         15          green   Dorothy
```

Can someone help with creating a merge statement?

Comment: Wow, nested cursor ...

Comment: Read your question.  How do you think we are able to help you???  We don't even know what you want.  All you do is post some sample input and your very long running query.

Comment: This is *tl;tr*, but - out of intuition - I'd suggest to read about [updateable CTEs](https://blog.sqlauthority.com/2014/05/19/sql-server-cte-can-be-updated/) or the [MERGE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/merge-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) statement. I'm pretty sure, that you don't need a CURSOR for this..

Comment: Have you tried a correlated sub-query?  They are wicked-fast. If you aren't familiar with them take a look at this and see what you think. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14295152/update-query-with-correlated-subquery

Comment: It's great you've posted sample data as DDL+DML, but your question is missing a description of what it is you want to accomplish. Pretty sure nested cursor is not the best solution (It's very rare what a cursor is the best solution, let alone nested cursors). If you could [edit] your question to provide an explanation that would give you a much better chance of getting a correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

Believe you just need to sum duration from the matching values in the appointment table and subtract it from the other table

Created select statement to return data, you will just need to save it off to your desired destination

```
SELECT start_date,a.begintime,a.endtime,a.interval,a.color,a.description
    ,CalculatedRemainder = a.duration - ISNULL(SUM(CAST(b.duration AS INT)),0)
FROM tbl_1 AS A
LEFT JOIN tbl_2 AS B
    ON a.description = b.description
    AND A.start_date = b.appt_date
    AND (
            b.begintime BETWEEN a.begintime AND a.endtime
            OR b.endtime BETWEEN a.begintime AND a.endtime
        )
GROUP BY A.ID,start_date,a.begintime,a.endtime,a.interval,a.color,a.description,a.duration
```